# GRequests monkey patch warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, grequests

I get the following warning each time , though the module works as expected :

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grequests.py:21: MonkeyPatchWarning: Monkey-patching ssl after ssl has already been imported may lead to errors, including RecursionError on Python 3.6. It may also silently lead to incorrect behaviour on Python 3.7. Please monkey-patch earlier. See https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1016. Modules that had direct imports (NOT patched): ['urllib3.util (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py)', 'urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py)']. 
  curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False)
```

I tried the workaround mentioned at [this github issue](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1016) but that doesn't work.

How to get rid of this warning ?

Comment: Are you import requests and grequests at the same time? it may also cause the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For **grequests** you would need to add the following code before other modules try to import / load gevent and ssl:

```
from gevent import monkey as curious_george
curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False)
```

Answer (score 5):

see grequests documentation:
https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests

GOOD:

```
import grequests 

import requests
```

BAD:

```
import requests 

import grequests
```